Правильно ли обращение?
Обращение: Дорогие родители города Н.
Мне это слышится как обращение к тем, кто создал город, а не к родителям детей.

Мне нравятся задачи  про детей)  Давайте напишем так: Дорогие родители детей в городе N!

"Родители детей". Надо полагать, бывают родители внуков.

Альтернативный вариант:
Дорогие родители-N-чи (москвичи, ростовчане и др.)!

Никогда не слышала, чтобы к основателям города так обращались. Думаю, вас правильно поймут, если вы оставите фразу, особенно, если в этот момент вы будете стоять среди родителей :)

Дорогие каменщики города N.! Тут нет ничего странного. Просто досужие домыслы. Хотя слово дорогие в этом предложении слегка неуместно.

По структуре правильно. И будь на месте "родителей" сварщики, знаменитости или пенсионеры, не возникло бы двусмысленности. Но она есть, и ради чистоты смысла предложение нужно переделать. Думаю, вы не нуждаетесь в чужих вариантах, так как задача уровня детского сада. Только человек с раздутым самомнением сейчас бы принялся вам указывать, куда всунуть причастный оборот и т.п. Я в вас верю, справитесь.

Вечер добрый, Третий глаз! Простите, а где в обращении причастный оборот, который вы рекомендуете куда-то всунуть?

@РиммаМихайлова нигде, но его можно применить: "родители, проживающие в..." и т.п.
